# How to take offset difference of a column without using `order by` and

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Right now this code is doing what it needs to do. I just feel like that the function `LAG` should have an easier way to take basically `OFFSET=-1`, which is not possible so I have to resort to the current code. What I do not like is that is every time I need this functionality I need to add 2 lines: 1 in the `SELECT` statement, 1 in the `ORDER BY` statement. Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same result in 1 line?

I do not care if `LAG` is replaced by another function, I am just interested in the final result being the same.

```sql
WITH mytable AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            (7),
            (6),
            (5),
            (4)
    ) AS t (time)
)
SELECT time,
       LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC) AS lagged_time
FROM mytable
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: Your code is already about as minimal as it gets.  I don't know how to simplify it and I also have no problem with it.

Comment: `LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC)`  == `LEAD(time) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC)` could it help?  An ORDER BY clause is the only method to ensure output is sorted as needed. You must include the clause if a specific ordering is requried.

Comment: @Serg thanks a lot, that was it! Didn't know `LEAD` existed. If you make it an answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LAG(time) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC)` == `LEAD(time) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC)`. An `ORDER BY` clause is the only method to ensure output is sorted as needed. You must include the clause if a specific ordering is requried.